# Detecting if user draws over given line

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing

I want to make a little iphone game where the User has to draw over a given line in a image. I know how to do the drawing code when the user touches the screen. But I have no clue how I can detect when the drawn line(s) are for example 95% over a given line in a png image.

An example of this is in the free 'dumb ways to die'-iphone/ipad game. The mini-game where you have to feed the snake by putting mustard on a hotdog.

Tips on how you would solve this problem are very welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Line intersection or just "above" a line?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would probably be to have a secondary (invisible) image of the same size that contains just the line, but with a thicker stroke. You could then simply check the pixel color in that secondary image for all the points of the line that is drawn by the user.